# If object is already in state dont add new entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello my goal is simple yet i find it hard to achieve:

I have the following function which is called everytime an user changes one of the fields in my form:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value , name , id } = e.target; 
    setFieldValues(prev => ([...prev, {value : value , field: name , project : id}]))   
}
```

And the form :

```
                <div className='simplicate-fields'> 
                    <span>KPI's</span>   
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <textarea defaultValue = {project.fieldKpi.value ? project.fieldKpi.value : null}  name={project.fieldKpi.id} id={project.projectId} onChange = {handleChange}></textarea>
                        <textarea defaultValue = {project.fieldContract ? project.fieldContract.value : null}  name={project.fieldContract.id} id={project.projectId} onChange = {handleChange}></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan"/>
                    </form>   
                </div>
```

Everytime i change the input value a new object gets added to the array. I dont want this ,if an object with the the field and project property already exists i simply want to update the value property instead of adding a whole new entry. I find it hard because i cannot mutate the state directly.

An example :

the initial state is just an array [];

if i make a change to my form the state will look like this :

```
[{field: 'job' , project : 123 , value : 'e'}]
```

if i make another change to the same field with the same properties except value this happens :

```
[{field: 'job' , project : 123 , value : 'e'} , {field: 'job' , project : 123 , value : 'en'}]
```

What i want is if the project and field are the same just do this :

```
[{field: 'job' , project : 123 , value : 'en'}]
```

and if i'd make another change :

```
[{field: 'job' , project : 123 , value : 'ent'}]
```

instead of creating new objects on every keyword i type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name, id } = e.target;
    setFieldValues(prev => {
        const existingIndex = prev.findIndex(el => (el.field === name) && (el.project === id));
        const newFields = [...prev];
        if (existingIndex >= 0) {
            newFields[existingIndex] = { ...newFields[existingIndex], value };
            return newFields;
        }
        newFields.push({ value: value, field: name, project: id });
        return newFields;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should be using an object instead of an array then?

Then your initial state can be {} and when you change something add its value to the already set object field.
For example the setFieldValues line would look something like this then assuming the `name` is unique:

```
setFieldValues(prev => ({...prev, name: {value : value , field: name , project : id}}))
```

If you need the state to be iterable you could also consider using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value , name , id } = e.target; 
    let projects = fieldValues.map(val => val.project);
    if (projects.includes(id) {
         let newFieldValues = [...fieldValues];
         newFieldValues[projects.indexOf(id)] = { value, field: name, project: id }
         setFieldValues(newFieldValues)
         } else {
            setFieldValues(prev => ([...prev, {value, field: name , project : id}]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
class inputForm extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { input1: "", input2: "", input3: false };
}

const changeHandler = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
```

input fields example:

```
<Form.Control type="text" name="input1" value={this.state.input1} onChange={(ev)=>this.changeHandler(ev.target.name, ev.target.value)} />
<Form.Control type="text" name="input2" value={this.state.input2} onChange={(ev)=>this.changeHandler(ev.target.name, ev.target.value)} />
<Form.Check name="input3" checked={this.state.input3} onChange={(ev)=>this.changeHandler(ev.target.name, ev.target.checked)} />
```

I used react-bootstrap components for input fields. Of course the input3 is a checkbox.

Oh I forgot this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

I used the bracket notation to access the proper state in changeHandler callback

Answer (score 0):

Try to override object you already set by creating new one each time, so it will override fields that aren't set yet with new values

```
setFieldValues(prev =>([ 
  Object.assign(prev, {value , field: name , project: id})
]))
```

If you don't have to keep fields in an array, just do

```
setFieldValues(prev => ({...prev, {value, field: name, project: id}})
```